# Test already tested rails app with rspec and cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I've started a project on rails, and so far I'm testing it using rails' built in test suite. Is there a way to start testing it using rspec and cucumber at this point? How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really weird question. What do you mean you've been using Rails' built-in test suite? What version of Rails are you using?

To start with testing, say models, in RSpec, you invoke the following command in Rails 3:

```
rails generate rspec:model <ModelName>
```

In Rails 2.x:

```
script/generate rspec:model <ModelName>
```

Cucumber is a bit different, but it starts with (Rails 3):

```
rails generate cucumber:install
```

Rails 2.x:

```
script/generate cucumber
```

All of this information is easily accessible on their respective Github pages. Is there anything more specific you need?

Comment: I've been developing the app using the normal rails generators, ie. `rails generate model`, `rails g scaffold`, and testing modifying the files in the /test folder. Any way to start using rspec and cucubmer now?

Comment: Well, rspec will generate files in the /spec directory, so after you execute the above command, that's where you need to look. However, if you've already started using TestUnit, which is the built-in framework, you should probably continue using that. There's no reason why you need to switch.